# 1982 yamaha seca 750 engine wont turn over

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

my 750 seca will not turn over, my uncle gave it to me, its been sitting for a couple years, I put P B blaster in cyilinders, and removed spark plugs and tried to push it to get it to turn but... can any one suggest some fixes?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the plugs and spraying a freeing liquid in there and leaving i for a week. Once you get it to turn over, make sure you spin on the starter to get what is left out - otherwise you can get hydraulic lock and seriously damage piston, rod or crank. Then change the oil - as the freeing liquid may have got in to it - worth changing anyway... then put the plugs back in and try to start it. If that does not work you may need to dismantle further to find what it is.

Comment: Automatic transmission (Dexron or whatever) fluid works good in these situations. Yup, still need to be careful of hydrolock, but it will unstick the piston/rings as good as anything and is a lot more common (more people will have a bottle of this around than a bottle of freeing liquid).